# AngularJS : Appending the same structure on the click of each item

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

My index.html page is like following:

```
<div id="sidepanel" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<ul class="drop-down">
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">
        <a href="#">{{item.name}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="mainpanel" ng-controller="listCtrl">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

For this ng-view I have record-list.html to show all the records which is like following:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="design">
        <li id="{{record.name}}" ng-repeat="record in records">
            <div>......</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now i want to add the same structure (as like each record) append on the click of each item of the side panel.

what is the logic for that ?

My recent UI Looks like this & i want to add the same structure on each click which should be append the existing structure.

[image]

Please Help.Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I'm a little confused. Let me clarify. On the click of a button you want to add a "record" to the view in that order?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like perhaps each "record" has a set of children "records." If this is the case, I would recommend using angular's ng-switch directive to conditionally display the correct (or no) set of sub-records on the side.