# AngularJS: data-ng-model & data-ng-hide/show

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

My index.html page is like as follows:

```
<div id="sidepanel" data-ng-controller="ListCtrl">
    <li data-ng-repeat="record in records">
    {{record.id}}
    <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="addwidget">
    </li>
</div>
<div id="main">
    <div data-ng-view></div>
</div>
```

for this data-ng-view i have another page recordlist.html in that i have following code:

```
<div data-ng-controller="ListCtrl">
    <ul class="design">
        <li data-ng-repeat="record in records"> 
           <div data-ng-switch data-on="record.category">
        <div data-ng-switch-when="reporting1">
             <div id="{{record.id}}" data-ng-show="addwidget">{{record.description}}</div> 
             </div>               
             <div data-ng-switch-when="reporting2">                
             <div id="{{record.id}}" data-ng-hide="addwidget">{{record.description}}</div>
             </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My question is i want to show the first div when i check the checkbox & when i uncheck it i want to show the second div.When both of the data-ng-model & data-ng-hide/show are on the same page then it works fine but in my case it present on two different pages.

Is it correct ? How can i implement this. Need Help.Thanks.

Comment: Can you create a plunkr for this? Its much easier to provide a solution if you do.

Comment: ngView is used when you have a routing setup in angular.  You should see the example in the page to restructure your app.  http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngView

Comment: @ganaraj : Here is the plunkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/iDOVkbWOvbKfLjDsnJU4

Comment: I also have one unanswered question. please help in this also if you can. thanks in advance. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16141559/angularjs-appending-the-same-structure-on-the-click-of-each-item?rq=1

Comment: @Jvaibhav can you create a plunker for that as well ? You should understand that creating a plunkr increases your chance of getting an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting `addwidget` in the first controller, but is trying to use it in the second. Controllers are not singletons.

So, in this situation:

```html
<div id="sidepanel" data-ng-controller="ListCtrl">
  ...
</div>
<div id="main">
  <div data-ng-view>
    <div data-ng-controller="ListCtrl">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You got two separated controllers and scopes. And you are setting `addwidget` in the first trying to read in the second.

You can either bind it to the root scope `$root.addwidget` or use a service share to the states.

As you have many records, binding directly to root is a problem, as all of them are going to share the same state. So you gonna need an object in the rootScope and bind the option by id `$root.addwidget[record.id]`. Made a pretty simplified [modification here](http://plnkr.co/edit/U2qfl8uHobcixZTIbcAd?p=preview).

Comment: Thank-you. Can you solve this problem ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16141559/angularjs-appending-the-same-structure-on-the-click-of-each-item?rq=1